# Failing Hard Drive

Tags: hard-drive, time-machine, migration

I have a Mac Pro I got in 2008. The original hard drive is failing. I have purchased a replacement drive and have backed up all my data using Time Machine. I will want to put the Mac OS on the new drive upon installation. The Apple Store said they would image a copy of the OS to the new drive free of charge. The CPU is a beast, so i would rather not have to lug it around if i can avoid it. Is there an easy way for me to migrate my OS installation from one hard drive to another?

Thank you!

Comment: So you do not want to use the Apple store offer?

Comment: Not clear what os you want, do you have the original cd disks?

Answer (score 1):

If the original drive is in a good enough state to read from, Carbon Copy Cloner will make a bootable clone of it - https://www.bombich.com - it might even manage if the drive is struggling - https://support.bombich.com/hc/en-us/articles/202255528-The-Cloning-Coach-Expert-advice-for-common-error-conditions